# Cloud Firestore database schema for chat app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a chat application based on the guide on this link : https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-chat-application-flutter-firebase-1d2e87ace78f

The difference is that in my chat app, the conversation between two users concern a specific subject. For instance conversation between user1 and user2 will be about subject1.

There is a list of subjects posted by users and when a user clicks on the subject, he/she can chat with the subject owner for clarification.

in the guide, the conversations are stored as such :
Firestore.instance
.collection('messages')
.document(chatId)
.collection(chatId).
.doc(timestamp)...

[image: sample image from the guide]

but since each message in my case is about a specific subject, I am using
Firestore.instance
.collection('messages')
.doc(subjectId)
.collection("subjectId")
.document(chatId)
.collection(chatId).
.doc(timestamp)...

Now my problem: when a user clicks on a subject and starts a chat with the owner, retrieving the messages and displaying them in the chatroom (chat Page) is not a problem because I know the specific subjectId and I can retrieve the messages with it.
But I have a message Page where user can see all the chats he/she has participated in.
something like this:

[image]

but since I don't have a specific subjectId, I am having trouble writing a query to retrieve all the conversations where the chatId contains my userId.

I will take help for better database schema to use or a way to write my query. Please
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [Collection Group query](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/collectionGroup.html).

As explained in the doc:

> A collection group consists of all collections with the same ID. By
> default, queries retrieve results from a single collection in your
> database. Use a collection group query to retrieve documents from a
> collection group instead of from a single collection.

Comment: Hey @Ktrel, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Hi. Yes I did. took me a little time to understand how to use properly.. but it helped. thanks.